# Change title tag with filter wpseo_title

Tags: php, seo, title

I am trying to change the title tag adding a variable (product-brand), but the variable does not show up.

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_product_wpseo_title');
     function filter_product_wpseo_title() {
        return 'hello'. $_GET[$mysite_slugs['product-brand']] .'hello';
     };
}
```

Also tried this but no luck

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_product_wpseo_title');
  function filter_product_wpseo_title() {
            $productbrand = $_GET[$mysite_slugs['product-brand']];
            return 'hello'. $productbrand .'hello';
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your URL has the parameter `.com/?product-brand=foo`. Make sure you have added the priority to your filter. This should do the trick!

```
add_filter('wpseo_title', 'filter_product_wpseo_title', 10, 1);

function filter_product_wpseo_title($title) {
    $title = 'hello '. $_GET['product-brand'] .' hello';
    return $title;
}
```